# TextBox C#. Разная длина у символов

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Когда открываем файл блокнотом видим, что у символов одинаковая длина.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вставляем этот текст в TextBox, получается такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Используйте моноширинный шрифт.

Comment: Посмотрите какой шрифт установлен в блокноте и установите такой же для своего TextBox'а